# Analog of function range in golang

Tags: go

Range in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php 
To create such an array, need use a slice?
I only know the method using the slice and loop for, but can there be another, more efficient way?

Comment: You can't make it more efficient than a for loop, the php range function just hides it from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In golang, there is only one iteration construct and that's the for loop. There are multiple ways to configure the for loop itself, but overall there is just the single construct:

https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1

https://play.golang.org/p/wBSGJqHuLK

```
The C method -- for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { }
The python method -- for k, v := range map[string]string{"key": "val"} { }
The python method -- for idx, val := range []string{"one", "two"} { }
The empty for -- for { }
```